# Right group axioms from left group axioms

Tags: group-theory

I was working a question in group theory where we are given that the left axioms hold for a set $G$ together with a binary operation $*$. We would then like to prove that $(G, *)$ is a group. I read a solution, but I came up with something different and wanted to clarify that what I've done is correct for one part of the proof, namely that the left identity $e$ is also a right identity. Here's what I wrote.

The left axioms that we'll use are $e * x = x$ and $x' * x = e$.

Let $x \in G$ and $e$ be the left identity in $G$. We need to show that $x * e = x$.

Now, $x * e = x \iff x * e = e * x  \iff x' * ( x * e) = x' * (e * x) \iff e * e = x' * x \\ \iff e = e$

which is true hence the right identity property holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. It might be clearer to write it backwards:

$e = e$ (self-evident)

$e \ast e = x' \ast x$ (since $x$ has a left-inverse, and $e$ is a left-identity).

$(x' \ast x) \ast e = x'\ast (e\ast x)$ (same reasoning, but applied to different sides of the equation).

$x'\ast(x \ast e) = x' \ast (e\ast x)$ (by associativity-this is crucial).

$(x')'\ast(x'\ast(x \ast e)) = (x')'\ast(x'\ast(e\ast x))$ (since every element has a left-inverse, including $x'$).

$((x')'\ast x')\ast(x \ast e) = ((x')'\ast x')\ast(e\ast x)$ (associativity, again)

$e\ast(x\ast e) = e\ast(e\ast x)$ (since $(x')'\ast x' = e$)

$x\ast e = e\ast x = x$ (since $e$ is a left-identity (used twice)).

---

Notice that your FORWARD implications are clear, but the REVERSE implications are not quite as clear, particularly:

$x'\ast(x\ast e) = x'\ast(e\ast x) \implies x\ast e = e\ast x$, in other words you have blithely assumed that such a set $G$ is *left-cancellative*: this is indeed true, but it needs clarification (which is why I introduce $(x')'$ to "cancel with"). You should also understand that we *need* associativity for this proof to go through (or else we cannot be certain that $x'\ast(x \ast e) = (x'\ast x)\ast e = e\ast e = e$).

Comment: Another user deleted his answer, but I had pointed out to him that I was fully aware that I used associativity and left-cancellation.

Comment: It's good that you understand that. Be aware, however, that your professor (or whoever grades your papers) may not know that you know, unless you say it somewhere. It's somewhat of a judgement call, to be sure, of how much detail to provide, and how much to leave out. But yes, you're idea is correct, and your reasoning sound.